# Add Lambda function to AWS AppSync Data Source?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to follow [this tutorial on the AWS Site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-programming-guide.html#setup).

I added the **GraphQL Schema** but then when I try to add the **Lambda Function** in the **Data Sources** I can't add it because the **Function ARN** field is disabled.

[image: aws]

How do I add Lambda function to AWS AppSync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drop-down lets you select an AWS Lambda function from the region selected in the "Region" drop-down. If you don't see anything populated in the list, it usually means that no Lambda functions exist in that region.

Can you check if you have Lambda functions in SA-EAST-1?

Comment: how to check that? do I have to go somewhere else to add Lambda function in SA-EAST-1? if so it is not mentioned in the tutorial & I'm an aws noob :(

Comment: You can check here: https://sa-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=sa-east-1#/functions

You can toggle the region in the region selector on the top right.

Comment: thank you I made it work & saw the CloudWatch Logs too